# How to integrate laravel packages?

Tags: php, laravel, package, forum

my next question is about Laravel, especially how to integrate custom packages. I have downloaded that package:

https://github.com/Riari/laravel-forum

Following the instructions i have installed it and registered the Providers, but now i am not able to integrate that forum in the laravel application, that i am developing. I am newbie to Laravel, so i have totally no clue how to start with.
I have searched for any tutorials, but found nothing.

If anybody can show me how to integrate the above package or give me a nice tutorial about integrating packages with laravel i will be thankful.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Did you try running the following command?

```
composer require riari/laravel-forum:~3.0
```

That should update your composer.json and add the new dependency.
Also, have a look at the guide that you can find in the [repo](https://github.com/Riari/laravel-forum#step-1-install-the-package).

Comment: i have installed it. But i dont know how to use it in my code ?

Comment: Best thing you can do here is to read [the documentation](http://teamteatime.net/docs/laravel-forum/introduction.md). To be fair, their docs seems pretty well organised.